# How to execute multiple scenarios in Jmeter concurrently

Tags: parallel-processing, jmeter, load-testing, execution

I am trying to perform load testing for my Web Application. Have created a Test plan with 16 scenarios using a single thread group. I have [added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4gLu.png) multiple sampler requests under each scenario and used throughput controllers for each of these.
But when the test is run, I noticed that the scenarios are running sequentially whereas i Want the scenarios to run in parallel.
Can someone help me with this please.

Answer (score 0):

This is how JMeter works. Each thread (virtual user) starts executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))

[image]

When you add more threads (virtual users) there will be some concurrency, as it evidenced by [__threadNum() and __time() functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) output:

[image]

So just provide enough threads (virtual users) and loops (iterations) on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level and you will get the concurrency you're looking for